# MYSQL and Facebook (FBML)

Tags: php, facebook, fbml

I am trying to develop a facebook application, I am using the FBML not iframe option. I would like to know if it's possible to use MYSQL with FBML?

When switching over to FBML I get the following error: "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 113"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't FBML problem. As canvas applications are simple iframes the problem is on your server side. Try to run the script on your server like this: example.com/myfbmlcanvasscript/ If you see the same error you know it isn't because of facebook.

The error itself come when something wrong with IP addresses. I am not sure what it exactly means.